# Best way to create pList in IOS

Tags: ios, plist

Which is the better way for creating pList;
would that be better if I create it programatically or through clicking resource and adding a pList file to our program. Please explain?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how and when you intend to write plist properties. If you want to add properties at run time you should create it programmatically or else you can add it via `add new files`

Answer (score 0):

its always better create plist programmaticaly in Document folder of application  for read and write data to plist but if you want to only fetch the data you can create plist via add new file and fill all data mannualy and fetch data from plist of bundle .
thanks